# Show more / Show less that stays on page whenever refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So after implementing the jQuery code of a previous question I noticed the following, whenever people add a product that is located in the show less / show more menu the system refreshes the page as it recalculates the price and therefore also the page. But when this happens the menu closes and then they would need to click the show more button again. How can this be fixed?

```js
//this will execute on page load(to be more specific when document ready event occurs)
if ($('.ty-compact-list').length > 3) {
  $('.ty-compact-list:gt(2)').hide();
  $('.show-more').show();
}

$('.show-more').on('click', function() {
  //toggle elements with class .ty-compact-list that their index is bigger than 2
  $('.ty-compact-list:gt(2)').toggle();
  //change text of show more element just for demonstration purposes to this demo
  $(this).text() === 'Show more' ? $(this).text('Show less') : $(this).text('Show more');
});
```

```css
.ty-compact-list {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 0px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.show-more {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="ty-compact-list">Product 1</div>
  <div class="ty-compact-list">Product 2</div>
  <div class="ty-compact-list">Product 3</div>
  <div class="ty-compact-list">Product 4</div>
  <div class="ty-compact-list">Product 5</div>
  <div class="ty-compact-list">Product 6</div>
  <div class="show-more">Show more</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use localstorage to store the last length of the shown products, that way you can do this.

Answer (score 1):

As Mohit said, you can use localStorage, your code would look like this:

```
var isCompactListOpen = localStorage.getItem('isCompactListOpen') || false;

function setButtonText() {
  if (isCompactListOpen) {
    $(this).text('Show less');
  } else {
    $(this).text('Show more');
  }
}

if ($('.ty-compact-list').length > 3) {
  setButtonText();
  $('.show-more').show();
  if (!isCompactListOpen) {
    $('.ty-compact-list:gt(2)').hide();
  }
}

$('.show-more').on('click', function() {
  //toggle elements with class .ty-compact-list that their index is     bigger than 2
  $('.ty-compact-list:gt(2)').toggle();
  //change text of show more element just for demonstration purposes to this demo
  isCompactListOpen = !isCompactListOpen;
  localStorage.setItem('isCompactListOpen', isCompactListOpen);
  setButtonText();
});
```

Comment: This does not work for me, it does show the show more / show less button but the functionality isnt there. Just on thing to keep in mind @Simon Jentsch is that I use jquery 1.11.1 and 1.9.1.

Comment: I can't get it to work on the snippet because it is sandboxed (localStorage access won't work). Do you have any JS errors with this solution that could cause the functionality not being there?

Comment: Well it does show the following: <!-- moved inline script to the bottom of the page -->

Comment: That doesn't really help. What functionality is not working? the complete button or the memorising the old state functionality?

Comment: Sorry for the vague answer, the button does show but all the elements are shown and not hidden. So basically the button doesnt function. It does show up but somehow the script doesnt work.

Comment: One further question: Are you using a server for this or just open the file from the file system? Because localStorage only works when there is a web server involved.

Comment: I do use a server with nginx, php7, mysql running on ubuntu 16.04